# connection to the Bitvise SSH Server

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-xp

I tested connection using  localhost (as it written in documentation) and connection was successful (I got opened terminal and SFTP)

I set port forwarding on the router.  I am located inside  network. There are no firewalls.

When I connect from different computer I get some problems.
Client even can connect to the SSH server, but connection is immediatly interrupted after it has been established.

It's log:
[image]

I can't make up any reason what  can  be a cause of the problem

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Does bitvise ssh server have an option to increase log verbosity?

Comment: unfortunately, no

Comment: the same problem for freesshd too

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are using private/public key pairs, check the permissions on the `authorized_keys` file. The file should only be read/write for the user and in a directory that is read/write/execute by the user only. This should have been an issue durring the localhost test but it is always a good idea to check.

Try to telnet from the client to the port: you should get something like what I get when trying mine
`SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1`
this will show that the ports are correct, open, and the daemon is running.

If you have turned off tunneled passwords (a good idea once you get it running) turn them back on until you can eliminate key issues as the problem.

If you can't get it running, i may need more info:
What port? I see you running on both 33934 and 58302. Which is correct?
Key or Password? Each has its own issues.
What does the log file on the server say? You can set OpenSsh's daemon to log more verbosely. It may be rejecting because of its own issues.
Is the Bitvise key in a format it likes?
Are you trying to SSH as root? This may (should) be turned off also.

Comment: hi, thanks you for your response.  As client I use Putty programme on Lubuntu 12.04, my connection parameters http://imm.io/BQJm   Log of client is http://imm.io/BQJx   Full setups of client http://paste.org.ru/?seskac    Computers are inside a local network, there is a router, its setups http://imm.io/BQJL   and  http://minus.com/lXpdhpBrtwPEj  Server is working on Windows XP SP3. Firewall on Windows is disabled. As server is used KSH, log of it is  http://paste.org.ru/?sz6iro      Setups of KSH  http://paste.org.ru/?24p7kj   I don't use authorized_keys.